# How to stop firing parent click event when child event clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have this structure of `div`s and I want to prevent parent click event from triggering when the child element is clicked.

```
    <div onclick='methods(param)'>
     <div></div>
     <div>
      <button onclick='method2(param2)'></button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I tried passing event with each `onclick` method but still it does not prevent parent click event.

Comment: There's no jQuery in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass & use the event object and use `stopPropagation`

```js
function methods(e) {
  console.log(' Parent function')
}

function method2(e) {
  console.log(' Child function');
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick='methods()'>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <button onclick='method2(event)'>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```